# BASH Command Not Found

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to count the number of HDD's on my linux system, I have put together the following line.

```
findhdds=$(find /sys/block -name 'sd*' | wc -l)
```

Now it seems to work when just running 'find /sys/block -name 'sd*' | wc -l' but when trying to store it in a variable I get the following message when reading it back:

```
3: command not found
```

Anyone understand where I have gone wrong?

Comment: What do you mean with "when reading it back"? You store it in a variable already. Does this message appear when you "echo" the variable "findhdds"? (Your code as such is correct; you might, just for the fun of it, provide absolute paths for find and wc - or, explicitely set the PATH variable so that "find" and "wc" will be found).

Comment: Do you "read the variable back" with `echo $findhdds` ?

Comment: yes sorry i meant when I echo it back

Comment: Please provide some sample code. There is nothing wrong with your command substitution.

Comment: I think you left out the `echo` here. If you only type `$findhdds` in  the shell you get something like `-bash: 3: command not found` because 1) the variable has the value `3` and 2) your shell tries to invoke a program named `3` . You should try: `echo $findhdds` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Explanation of *bug*

Some version/implementation of `wc` made formatted output and put spaces before the value you coud try:

```
$ wc -l < <(find /sys/block/ -name 'sd*')
  3
```

Please, note that output of `wc` contain spaces. Now try:

```
$ findhdds= 3
bash: 3: command not found
```

to obtain the error reported in SO's question.

## Two solutions (and more...):

### .1 compute answer to ensure this become a number:

```
findhdds=$((0+$(find /sys/block/ -name 'sd*' | wc -l)))
```

Or (I like this):

```
findhdds=$[$(find /sys/block/ -name 'sd*' | wc -l)]
```

Both of them will store number only in variable:

```
echo $findhdds 
3
```

### .2 Store devices names in an array an count members:

You could use bash for doing what `wc` does:

```
$ findhdds=($(find /sys/block/ -name 'sd*'))

$ echo $findhdds
/sys/block/sda

$ echo ${#findhdds[@]}
3

$ echo ${findhdds[2]}
/sys/block/sdc
```

### Pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

At all, in **this** particular case, you could use bash for the whole job:

#### Simply:

```
findhdds=(/sys/block/sd*)
```

#### Count

```
echo ${#findhdds[@]}
3
```

#### Indices

```
echo ${!findhdds[@]}
0 1 2
```

#### All disks (with full paths)

```
echo ${findhdds[@]}
/sys/block/sda /sys/block/sdb /sys/block/sdc
```

#### One of them

```
echo ${findhdds[0]}
/sys/block/sda
```

#### Only the device name

```
echo ${findhdds[0]##*/}
sda

echo ${findhdds[@]##*/}
sda sdb sdc
```

#### ... could be processed in a loop:

```
for devnam in ${findhdds[@]##*/} ; do
    printf "Doing something with device: %s...\n" $devnam
  done
Doing something with device: sda...
Doing something with device: sdb...
Doing something with device: sdc...
```

Answer (score 3):

If you store a command into a variable, calling this variable directly will execute the result. That's why it's trying to launch the command 3, which obviously doesn't exist.
You have to print the variable to see the result:
echo $findhdds

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
findhdds=`find /sys/block/ -name 'sd*' | wc -l`
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: command substitution can be done with the dollar sign OR the backquote sign.